# Not reading the form element in the while loop first iteration ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a while loop that runs 5 times:

```
string qry = "Select * from tbl_Products order by ProductId";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
con.Open();
sbProducts="<table><tr>"; 
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
{ 
    while (sdr.Read()) 
    {
        sbProducts = sbProducts + "<td>";
        sbProducts = sbProducts + "<Form>";
        sbProducts = sbProducts + "123";
        sbProducts = sbProducts + "</Form>";
        sbProducts = sbProducts + "</td>"; 
    }
    sbProducts = sbProducts + "</table>";
    CellTwo = sbProducts.ToString();
    con.Close(); 
}
```

Its output is fine but it is not wrapping the first iteration TD is not wrap with form tag. 
It seems to be very illogical. The output is like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>123</td>
<td><form>123</form></td>
<td><form>123</form></td>
<td><form>123</form></td>
<td><form>123</form></td>


</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ...what is sbProducts initially? Where/how are you writing it out to? Also `sbProducts += "<td>";` is a shorter way to write it.

Comment: Are you sure the while loop runs 5 times?

Comment: sbProducts  is a string.

Comment: @Jojo there is no indication that is how it is supposed to look in your edit... and also wouldn't compile.

Comment: asp.net = only 1 form

Comment: @giammin that is not true. ASP.NET = 1 form with `runat=server`. You can have as many non-nested forms as you want. HTML = no form with children form.

Comment: @UsmanMasood please show how you initialize sbProducts and how you are writing out the end product. Why is your output lowercase?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev would you suggest someone to have multiple forms in an asp.net app?

Comment: string qry = "Select * from tbl_Products order by ProductId";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        con.Open();
        sbProducts="<table><tr>";
using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
while (sdr.Read())
            {
sbProducts = sbProducts + "<td>";
sbProducts = sbProducts + "<Form>";
sbProducts = sbProducts + "123";
sbProducts = sbProducts + "</Form>";
sbProducts = sbProducts + "</td>";
} sbProducts = sbProducts + "</table>";CellTwo = sbProducts.ToString();con.Close();
}
}

Comment: @giammin yes, I do it all the time. The problem is, default masterpage wraps entire body in form tag with `runat=server`, which is why many people think you only get one form. It doesn't have to be that way. As long as there is only one form tag with `runat=server`, and you don't have a form within a form, you can have as many forms as you want. ASP.NET MVC is more common practice to have multiple forms, but webforms is OK too.

Comment: your question appears to be tagged javascript. Do you have some javascript processing happening on load that might remove the form tag ?

Comment: @UsmanMasood you are missing the `</tr>`. What is CellTwo? It's curious that your output doesn't match what you show in your loop.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev how do you handle posts of the forms?

Comment: @giammin ...they post where I tell them to post. Multiple forms on a page is not something the entire world can use except ASP.NET developers.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev and you think this is a good practice in asp.net?

Comment: @giammin there are tons of scenarios when you need multiple forms, so yes, it can be a good practice is that is what you need... though this comes up more in ASP.NET MVC then it does webforms. In webforms though I have a separate form tag for my site search box, and then everything else is inside the form with `runat=server`. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.
1) You aren't properly building a table (you were missing a `</tr>`)
2) That table is likely inside another form. Your code (slightly cleaned up) should look like:

```
while (sdr.Read()) 
{
    sbProducts += "<td>";
    sbProducts += "<Form>";
    sbProducts += "123";
    sbProducts += "</Form>";
    sbProducts += "</td>"; 
}
sbProducts += "</tr></table>"; //You were missing this </tr>
```

Once you verify that you **aren't** doing this **inside another form**, you'll see that it comes out as expected.  A form cannot contain another form, its an HTML standard.

Comment: this is not inside a for

Comment: Are you using a master page? Most default .aspx pages and master pages will start out like `<body><form id="form1" runat="server"...>`. I can replicate your problem exactly when putting it inside a form. Outside a form it works fine.

Comment: You may also notice there is a difference between the rendered HTML and what you see when you inspect element in something like firebug.

Comment: thanx Mike, its working now, u r right, there is a <form> tag in master page. The problem is soved by putting </form> in loop starting.

Comment: that is not a proper way to fix it... Also then you will have a random end form tag near the end of the document.